# Is there a way to copy or clone Koin scope as new scope instance?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, service-locator, koin, koin-scope

Using [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) library I'm trying to achive this behaviour:

```
val scopeA = getScope(ID)
val scopeB = scopeA.clone()
```

Short speaking, `clone()` should copy all instances from one scope to another.
So in this case I can modify `scopeB` without modifying the original `scopeA`.

Is this possible?